# Calendar Invites in Emails?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Does anyone know a method for attaching / creating a personal meeting invite attached to an email sent from Marketing Cloud?

I am fully aware of the method where we host an iCal file and link to that, however, in our use case - we are basing the mail on salesforce events, and would love to have this as a meeting invite to the email sent. Our context:

- We send an email when the meeting is created or changed
- We use journey builder for the send
- We would like for them to be able to add the meeting to their calendar

This is the base requirement - any ideas? :)

Also, I know that meetings should ideally be linked to one another, so that acceptances and changes are reflected in the original meeting, instead of us having to create a new meeting. Not sure how this would work though?

Looking forward to hear from you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would likely want to lead them to a LP that dynamically creates the ICS file.  I would recommend using something like [ICS.JS](https://github.com/nwcell/ics.js/) and then just include the information on the event in a DE or something (pull this via a lookup or SSJS retrieve) and just pass a unique key in the URL to the LP.

Overview:

1. Create a Data Extension (DE) to house your events data with a unique key to identify event (e.g. EventID). This allows you a single location to edit and update the event details - which will go into effect immediately.
2. Create a Landing Page (LP) to dynamically create an ICS file (via ICS.JS or similar).  You will need to lookup event details from the DE Server side though or via API.
3. In the email link to the LP passing the unique key for the event(e.g. `www.yourLPlink.com?EventID=12345678`)

This would allow you to constantly utilize the same page for all events and updates and you would only need to enter the info into the DE and edit the parameter on the URL to use it.

Comment: Hey Gortonington ! I'll have a look at this process - it seems like this could be the way to go! :) Am i correct to assume that you would need to link to the LP in the email, and then it will hit a landing page and upon hitting it, it will suggest to add the event to your calendar?
Do you know of any solution that does this directly in the email? (so the attachment is present immediately? Potentially using SSJS scripts combined with the ICSJS functionality? or?

Comment: You likely could attach it via the AMPscript function using the LP as the endpoint or just have the link automatically download the file to the computer after it is created.